# SQL: multiple entries with different attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have just 1 entries for each zipcode but atm I have more than one entry. Here is the code:

```
select * from xyz
order by plz
```

And this is the result:

```
Zipcode   Longitude   Latitude
-----------------------------------
01067   13,7143948  51,0592796
01067   13,6753     51,0837
01067       
01067   13,6649834  51,0426555
01067   13,7617695  51,0538158
01067   13,75       51,05
01067   13,7366     51,0507
01069   13,7366     51,0507
01069       
01069   13,75       51,05
01069   13,7617695  51,0538158
01069   13,6649834  51,0426555
01069   13,6753     51,0837
01090       
01097   13,6649834  51,0426555
01097   13,7617695  51,0538158
01097   13,6753     51,0837
01097   13,75       51,05
```

now I want to have only that zipcode with the highest "longitude"-value in my result select

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select zipcode, max(Longitude), max(Latitude) from xyz
group by zipcode
order by plz
```

You could other aggregators if needed (min, first, last...)

Answer (score 0):

Use
**[GROUP BY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm)**

```
select Zipcode,max(Longitude),max(Latitude) from xyz
group by Zipcode
order by plz
```

Answer (score 0):

he wanted max longitude only, so i guess we should wirte like this

```
select Zipcode, max(Longitude) , Latitude
from xyz
group by zipcode
order by plz
```

Comment: That syntax won't work in Oracle; you have to group by all non-aggregated columns. And if you grouped by `zipcode, latitude` then you'd get multiple rows for each `zipcode`, with different `lattitude`, but all with the same (max) `longitude`, which doesn't sound like what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

An analytic function might be appropriate here:

```
select zipcode, longitude, latitude
from (
    select zipcode, longitude, latitude,
        rank() over (partition by zipcode
            order by longitude desc nulls last) as rn
    from xyz
)
where rn = 1
order by zipcode;
```

Obligatory [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c94e7/2).

The `rank()` in the inner select assigns a ranking within each zip code, with the row with the highest latitude value being ranked as 1. The outer select just filters to only get those.